# Getting "End of input at character at 0" when trying to parse my JSON object

Tags: java, android, json

I am trying to parse my `JSON` response from a server, which seems fine when I just make a `System.out.println()` with the response, but when I try to parse it I get `JSONException: End of input at character 0;`

From what I have read it is because I'm trying to parse an array as an object or vice verse, but I can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong, some help or guidance what be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

    System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
    http.sendGet();

}


private void sendGet() throws Exception {

    String url = "myUrl";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();


    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("api-key");
    con.setRequestProperty("api-code");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);

    if (responseCode == 200) {
        InputStream inputStr = con.getInputStream();
        String encoding = con.getContentEncoding() == null ? "UTF-8" : con.getContentEncoding();
    }

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
        System.out.println("Body: " + response);
```

And here is the response I get from the server, which seems fine:

```
    {"id":"16165","sensorid":"cc3200_8A7F30","pm1":"0.22","pm25":"0.23","pm10":"0.41","timestamp":"2018-01-30 12:28:56.000"},{"id":"16166","sensorid":"cc3200_E271A6","pm1":"0","pm25":"0.02","pm10":"0.46","timestamp":"2018-01-30 12:30:15.000"},{"id":"16167","sensorid":"cc3200_8A7F30","pm1":"0.09","pm25":"0.09","pm10":"0.58","timestamp":"2018-01-30 12:30:56.000"},{"id":"16168","sensorid":"cc3200_E271A6","pm1":"0.07","pm25":"0.07","pm10":"0.26","timestamp":"2018-01-30 12:32:15.000"}
```

And here is my JSONParse class:

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        String jsonString = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonString);
        System.out.println("jsonstring" + jsonString.toString());

        if (jsonString != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                JSONArray particles = jsonObject.getJSONArray("particles");

                for (int i = 0; i < particles.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = particles.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String sensorid = c.getString("sensorid");
                    String pm1 = c.getString("pm1");
                    String pm25 = c.getString("pm25");
                    String pm10 = c.getString("pm10");
                    String timestamp = c.getString("timestamp");

                    HashMap<String, String> particle = new HashMap<>();
                    particle.put("id", id);
                    particle.put("sensorid", sensorid);
                    particle.put("pm1", pm1);
                    particle.put("pm25", pm25);
                    particle.put("pm10", pm10);
                    particle.put("timestamp", timestamp);


                }
            }catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json Parsing error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                });
            }
        }else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });
        }
        return null;
```

Comment: Server response must be inside Array because there are multiple objects.

Comment: As @NiranjPatel say Server response must inside array having key "particles"

Comment: above provide json response is not valid.

Comment: Oh okey, how do I make the response inside an array?

Comment: @Kkona can't change response from server ?

Comment: As of right now I can't really change what I get from the server, but is that the only solution?

Comment: @Kkona there is many solution but proper way is change from server

Comment: @NiranjPatel I see, I won't be able to reach the person running the server to fix that for a while, do you have any quick-fixes in the meantime?

Comment: @Kkona check my answer for quick-fixes

Comment: @Kkona [if found solution then you can accept right answer so it will help to other user in future](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
jsonString = "{ \"particles\":[" + jsonString + "] }" ;
```

**Use Like this**

```
try {
                jsonString = "{ \"particles\":[" + jsonString + "] }" ;

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                JSONArray particles = jsonObject.getJSONArray("particles");

        for (int i = 0; i < particles.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = particles.getJSONObject(i);

            String id = c.getString("id");
            String sensorid = c.getString("sensorid");
            String pm1 = c.getString("pm1");
            String pm25 = c.getString("pm25");
            String pm10 = c.getString("pm10");
            String timestamp = c.getString("timestamp");

            HashMap<String, String> particle = new HashMap<>();
            particle.put("id", id);
            particle.put("sensorid", sensorid);
            particle.put("pm1", pm1);
            particle.put("pm25", pm25);
            particle.put("pm10", pm10);
            particle.put("timestamp", timestamp);

            Log.i("TAG Id", ":" + id);
            Log.i("TAG sensorid", ":" + sensorid);
            Log.i("TAG pm1", ":" + pm1);
            Log.i("TAG pm25", ":" + pm25);
            Log.i("TAG pm10", ":" + pm10);
            Log.i("TAG timestamp", ":" + timestamp);


        }
  }
```

**OUTPUT LOG**

[image]

Comment: Well, I tried this and got another error than the one I had originally: Json Parsing error: Value {"particles":[]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: @Kkona which place are you put this line.

Comment: @Kkona please check my Edit answer.

Comment: In the beginning, right before the first Log.e(), should I place it somewhere else?

Comment: @Kkona it is working fine i am checking with output.

Answer (score 0):

If response can't change from server then just add bracket at start and end of response and use below code for parse data.

```
    String jsonString = sh.makeServiceCall(url);
    jsonString = "["+jsonString+"]";

    JSONArray particles = new JSONArray(jsonString);

    for (int i = 0; i < particles.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = particles.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = c.getString("id");
        String sensorid = c.getString("sensorid");
        String pm1 = c.getString("pm1");
        String pm25 = c.getString("pm25");
        String pm10 = c.getString("pm10");
        String timestamp = c.getString("timestamp");

        HashMap<String, String> particle = new HashMap<>();
        particle.put("id", id);
        particle.put("sensorid", sensorid);
        particle.put("pm1", pm1);
        particle.put("pm25", pm25);
        particle.put("pm10", pm10);
        particle.put("timestamp", timestamp);
    }
```